# Why is Linearity of Expectation so important?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I understand what linearity of expectation is. In short:

$E[\sum X_i] = \sum E[X_i] $

However I don't quite see its significance. That is, in what scenario does applying $E[\sum X_i]$ over $\sum E[X_i]$ (or vice versa) make a difference?

Comment: "Significance" is a subjective term. As far as I'm concerned, linearity of $E$ isn't significant, just convenient. It means that if you already know each $E[X_i]$, then $E[\sum X_i]$ is quite easy to compute.

Comment: also, note that it holds for finite summation only. In general you can't swap expectation and an infinite sum :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll try to give you an example that shows why it is very useful. Suppose that the  random variable $X$ follows the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$. Then the expected value of $X$ is given by
$$
\operatorname EX=\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
$$
But we know that $X=\sum_{j=1}^nY_j$, where $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables with the parameter $p$. Hence,
$$
\operatorname EX=\operatorname E\biggl[\sum_{j=1}^nY_j\biggr]=\operatorname \sum_{j=1}^nEY_j=np.
$$
So it's much easier to calculate the value of $\operatorname EX$ if we use the fact that $X=\sum_{j=1}^nY_j$.

Comment: And additionally, linearity of expectation holds no matter how the random variables are related, which can lead to an even worse mess. So for example you can compute the expected number of triangles in a random graph, even though the random variables are very correlated.

Answer (score 3):

It is very convenient that (more general) measures can be looked at as linear functions on suitable functions in the sense that $\mu(f+g)=\mu(f)+\mu(g)$ and $\mu(cf)=c\mu(f)$ where $\mu(f)$ denotes the integral over $f$ with respect to measure $\mu$.

One example in the smaller context of expectation: it makes it easy to find expectation of the binomial distribution. If $X$ is binomially distributed with parameters $n$ and $p$ then we can write $$X=X_1+\cdots+X_n$$ where the $X_i$ are iid and Bernouilli-$p$ distributed. That means that $X_i=1$ with probability $p$ and $X_i=0$ with probability $1-p$. It is easy to find that $\mathbb EX_i=p$ and with the linearity of expectation we find:
$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EX_1+\cdots+\mathbb EX_n=p+\cdots+p=np$$

That is much more efficient and elegant than applying $$\mathbb EX=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well like already said before "significance" is fairly subjective. But, if you want an application of that property, here it is one:

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ be a set of random variables representing loss, each with mean $\mu_1, \mu_2,..., \mu_n $. We want to pool our loss together so we set $ S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $, we want to find the expected pooled loss. Then $ E[S_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i $. 
In a more practical way say we know all the $X_i$'s are distributed $\sim$Exp($\lambda$), and are independent, then $E[S_n] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i = \sum_{i=1}^n 1/\lambda = \frac {n-1}{\lambda} $ .

Note that without knowing this property, you would have to find the convolution of all the $X_i$'s and then integrate them. i.e. $E[S_n] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty {s\cdot f_{S}(s)}ds$, where $f_S(s)$ is the transformation of $S_n = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$. Something that is not always very straight forward or easily computed.